# Keras gives error while training a model with fit generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

Hi I am training an UNET model for medical image segmentation, but when I use model.fit_generator like this:

```
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(patience=3, verbose=1)
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('model-dsbowl2018-1.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
results = model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, validation_steps=10, steps_per_epoch=250,
                          epochs=3, callbacks=[earlystopper, checkpointer])
```

I got an error such like:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
.
.
.

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't know why this is happening, maybe version difference of Keras, but i will be thankful for any help.

Comment: to try to isolate the problem, run fit without the callbacks and see if you still get the error.

Comment: yes @GerryP im still getting the same error without callbacks

Comment: need to see more of the code to help. Show generators and model

Comment: You need to include the complete traceback, do not edit it yourself.

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/lvntky/03c7232ea971905a4a36a3495fbc8c0c) here you can see the all the code